# Using $_GET with clean URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, seo

I know this has been asked many a time, but i cannot find the answers I'm looking for.

Basic bit of URL rewriting but first time doing it.

example url:

```
domain.com/viewbuild.php?id=25
```

Desired:

```
domain.com/viewbuild/25
```

Attempted htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ viewbuild.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

However, I am trying to use:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

But i am getting errors with this for undefined index.

I thought because i am rewriting the URL that GET variables would still work?

Thanks. Craig.

Edit as requested, full .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /viewbuild.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule !.*\.php$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Mind showing what `print_r($_GET)` returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$` expects a trailing slash, so it will only match `/viewbuild/25/`. Try this one:

```
RewriteRule ^viewbuild/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /viewbuild.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tested the rewrite here and it seems to work: http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/. Can you add the whole .htaccess file to your question?

Comment: @user2921557 Typically .htaccess is unrelated to undefined index errors. Undefined index means your looking for an array key which does not exist

Comment: @GergoErdosi I cannot get the rewrite working on that website. For the URL i am using: http://domain.com/viewbuild/25 and it returns this for the rewrite line 'This rule was not met because one of the conditions was not met'

Comment: @GergoErdosi just tried that example in the test website and it works. Appears to be something else in the htaccess causing issues. Anything obvious from the looks of things? I shall double check what i actually need in the htaccess later and see.

Comment: @user2921557 Unfortunately I don't see where the issue is. Might be a server configuration, might be your application code, etc. You need to do some more debugging to isolate the problem.